# ASP.NET MVC Create Custom Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and under the "home" controller I have a "careers" action that loads a careers page. So my current URL is "https://{mywebsite}/home/careers" and this works fine. Now the client has decided that he wants the url to be

```
https://{mywebsite}/careers
```

Do I need to add a new controller or can I do some kind of routing to achieve this without creating a new controller? I tried to add a rule in the `RouteConfig` but to no success...

Thanks

Comment: Create a careers controller

Comment: If your controllers do NOT contain any logic, then it should be fairly easy...

Answer (score 1):

The `careers` action method can be called with the "https://{mywebsite}/careers" URL if you will add the following routing mapping:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaulCareers",
        url: "careers",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "careers" }
    );
```

Or you can apply the `Route()` attribute:

```cs
[Route("careers")]
public ActionResult Careers()
{          
    ....
}
```

To enabling attribute routing it is necessary to include the following line in the `RegisterRoutes()` method:

```cs
// Enabling attribute routing. Recommend to put attribute routes in the route table before traditional routes.
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```